# Java Lambda - La variable 'X' local definida en un ámbito adjunto debe ser final

Tags: java, java-8, lambda, java-stream

Tengo un menú simple que hace estas dos cosas: mostrar la lista y filtrarla por `población`. Pero me lanza el siguiente error:

> Local variable poblacion defined in an enclosing scope must be final
>   or effectively final

¿Por qué me da un error con el parámetro población?
¿Se puede solucionar de alguna manera siguiendo la misma estrucutura?

Codigo:

```
public void seleccionarAlumnos(){
        int opcion = -1;
        String poblacion, sexo;
        List<Alumno> lista = clase.getListaAlumnos();
        do{
            try{
                opcion = menu();
                switch (opcion){
                case 1: verListaAlumnos(clase.getListaAlumnos()); break;
                case 2: poblacion = leerPoblacion();
                        lista.stream().filter(x-> x.getPoblacion().contains(poblacion)).forEach(System.out::println);break;

                case 0: break;
                default: System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                }
            }catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de opcion");
                teclado.nextLine();
            }
        }while (opcion != 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

> Local variable `poblacion` defined in an enclosing scope must be *final* or *effectively final*

**¿Significa esto que la única forma de usar una variable en un lambda es por medio de marcarla con `final`?**

No. Nota que el mensaje especifica 2 opciones válidas:

- final
- ***effectively*** final

Lo que esto quiere decir es que, sea que uses el keyword `final` o no, lo importante es que la variable nunca cambie.  Claro, una manera de garantizar esto es con el keyword `final`, pero es opcional.

La razón por la que quiero aclarar este punto es para que entiendas que, en tu caso, **el problema en realidad no es que te falte el keyword `final` al frente de la variable `poblacion`.  El problema de fondo es que no estás definiendo la variable `poblacion` en el lugar correcto.**

Al definir la variable `poblacion` fuera del bucle, significa que el valor de esta variable cambia a cada iteración, lo que viola la regla necesaria para que puedas usarla en el lambda:

```
String poblacion; // definido fuera del bucle
do {
    // ...
    poblacion = leerPoblacion(); // cambia a cada iteración
    lista.stream().filter(x-> x.getPoblacion().contains(poblacion)).forEach(System.out::println);
    // ...
} while (opcion != 0);
```

**Solución**

En realidad, la solución verdadera a tu problema es simplemente de mover la definición de la variable `población` **adentro** del bucle:

```
do {
    // ...
    String poblacion = leerPoblacion(); // diferente variable a cada iteración
    lista.stream().filter(x-> x.getPoblacion().contains(poblacion)).forEach(System.out::println);
    // ...
} while (opcion != 0);
```

Aunque a primera vista este cambio parece insignificante, porque en realidad la lógica del código no cambia, este pequeño cambio es suficiente para corregir el error. **Esto es porque, en vez de definir una variable `poblacion` que todas las iteraciones del bucle comparten y modifican, mas bien, cada iteración define su propia copia separada de la variable `poblacion` que no cambia después de la asignación inicial.**

Ahora bien, si deseas además agregarle el keyword `final`, tal vez para que la intención quede más clara, puedes hacerlo. Pero esto es opcional.

**Otra solución**

A veces, surgirán situaciones donde no puedes simplemente mover la definición de una variable, o impedir que esta siga cambiando.

En este caso, una solución alternativa perfectamente aceptable es de definir una segunda variable, al que le asignas la primera, con el único propósito de poder usarla en el lambda. De esta forma, puedes seguir usando y modificando la primera variable todo lo que quieras, mientras el lambda usa la segunda variable que no cambia.

Ejemplo usando tu código:

```
String poblacion; // definido fuera del bucle
do {
    // ...
    poblacion = leerPoblacion(); // cambia a cada iteración
    String copiaPoblacion = poblacion; // copia para el lambda
    lista.stream().filter(x-> x.getPoblacion().contains(copiaPoblacion)).forEach(System.out::println);
    // ...
} while (opcion != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que declarar la variable `poblacion` como `final`:

```
public void seleccionarAlumnos(){
    int opcion = -1;
    String sexo;
    List<Alumno> lista = clase.getListaAlumnos();
    do{
    try{
        opcion = menu();
        switch (opcion){
        case 1: verListaAlumnos(clase.getListaAlumnos()); break;
        case 2: 
                // declaramos como final la variable poblacion
                final String poblacion = leerPoblacion();
                lista.stream().filter(x-> x.getPoblacion().contains(poblacion)).forEach(System.out::println);break;

        case 0: break;
        default: System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
            }
        }catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de opcion");
            teclado.nextLine();
        }
    }while (opcion != 0);
}
```

La razon es porque no puedes utilizar una variable donde su valor pueda cambiar dentro de una funcion lambda. El valor tiene que ser constante y eso es lo que hace `final`.

Comment: El problema es que las variables final sólo puedo inicializarlas una vez y el valor de población varía según leerPoblacion();

Comment: Te lanza algun error? A mi no me lanza ninguno.

Comment: No me permite crear más cases que utilicen poblacion

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es la declarar la lista como un atributo de la clase, es decir, declararla fuera del método.

```
public class tuClase {
    String poblacion;
    public void seleccionarAlumnos(){
        int opcion = -1;
        String sexo;
        List<Alumno> lista = clase.getListaAlumnos();
        do{
        try{
            opcion = menu();
            switch (opcion){
            case 1: 
                verListaAlumnos(clase.getListaAlumnos()); break;
            case 2: 
                poblacion = leerPoblacion();
                lista.stream().filter(x-> x.getPoblacion().contains(poblacion)).forEach(System.out::println);break;   
            case 0: 
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
            }
            }catch (InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de opcion");
                teclado.nextLine();
            }
        }while (opcion != 0);
    }
}
```